# Meaning of "uniquely qualified roster"

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the bold part. Can someone help me?

> But with a **uniquely qualified roster** of clients.

Reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/roster.

Comment: What are you having problems with? "uniquely", "qualified" and "roster" all have meanings that are easily searchable in dictionaries. You've linked to a dictionary definitions of "roster", but I don't know why that hasn't answered your question unless you tell me.

Comment: The phrase, *a uniquely qualified roster of clients" is typical of the hyperbole practised by public relations firms wishing to promote certain interests. It's meant to sound impressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know the exact meaning of this phrase without context. However, you can guess that 'qualified' refers to the people on the roster.

The roster of clients will be a list of all of someone's clients. 'qualified' can refer to having received qualifications, such as GCSEs, degrees, or other skills or certificates.
So, the phrase suggests that the people on the roster have qualifications which are 'unique', unusual or rare.

Perhaps the clients have odd or not very useful degrees, or obscure skill sets, for example.